# How to make a clone ignore movement input when his parent is moving

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, parent-child

I use move_states to track character's movement, but it can only track itself, when the character splited into two characters, how to make the clone one ignore the player's input when his parent is moving.

[image]

the movement_input part of the script:

```c#
private void Movement_input() 
{
     if (move_states == 0) 
     {
         if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow)) 
         {
             move_states = 1;
             target_position = transform.position + new Vector3(0, 0.8f, 0);
         }
         else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.DownArrow)) 
         {
             move_states = 1;
             target_position = transform.position + new Vector3(0, -0.8f, 0);
         }
         else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
         {
             move_states = 1;
             target_position = transform.position + new Vector3(-1, 0, 0);
         }
         else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow)) 
         {
             move_states = 1;
             target_position = transform.position + new Vector3(1, 0, 0);
         }
     }
 }
```

Thank you for helping!

Comment: the interesting part is where you "clone" the object, you are instantiating the same object? which references have with the parent, etc try to post it please

Comment: Please add your code where you "clone" you object so we can (better) understand what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some choices.

For example: 
I would Instantiate the children separately and with a tag ("clone" for example) in each of them (even the first one). 
Then, everytime you try to move one of them (you have to figure out a way to decide which one gets priority) it has to check with a loop searching for objects with tag "clone" if anyone has move_states to 0.

Some of the code could be:

```
bool canMove = true;
for each (GameObject clone in GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag()){
    if (clone.GetComponent<script>().move_states == 1)
        canMove = false;
}
if(canMove == true)
    Movement_input();
```

Let me know if you get it working ;)

Comment: Thanks it worked. BUT i got a new problem T0T, you know the unity script runs linear, and the engine runs all the script traversal, so if anyone moving(move_states ==1), others can not move anymore. But how can i make them move togeter as before, and only the stuck one can not move when other's moving.(if they move right together, the one on the right is at the edge of the stage, so it's a stucked one)
if i press right arrorw and then press left arrorw immediately, the stucked one will walk left unexpectedly the moment the left one is walking right as well.
THANKS A LOT!!!

Comment: I fixed it by using LateUpdate, THX a lot.

Answer (score 1):

If I haven't understood wrong, you have an object that can be cloned and its script is also cloned. A simple solution would be disabling child's script no?.

When you say parent you mean hierarchy parent or just the cloned object? In case of hierarchy parent you can just detach the child from its parent.

Comment: Thank you very much for answering my question, and you understood it right. i use Object.Instantiate() to clone new objects, but acturally i wanted to track every cloned scripts including the first one, if their move_states are all equal to 0, then they can move , if any of them(cloned one or its parents)is moving , then none of others would move. so what methord can i use, or what function can i use, i tried GetComponentsInChildren but didn't make it, i am a newbie, so i really need your help, Thank you very much. by the way the move_states is a public int in this class.

Comment: All right, now I perfectly understand your problem (I hope).

Comment: Oops, pressed enter. Okay, better I answer in answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'd make the cloned objects a separate prefab altogether with another script. From the main script you can get references to the clones and call a method on them every time they should move. Something like this,

```
private Gameobject[] copies;
private int dir; 

public void MoveClones()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < copies.Length; i++)
    {
        copies[i].SendMessage("MoveDir", dir);
    }
}
```

And then your MoveDir funtion is in the clone object script with a single parameter for the direction. You can check the move state of itself there.

Comment: THANKS FOR HELPING, But how can i make them move togeter as before, and only the stuck one can not move when other's moving.(if they move right together, the one on the right is at the edge of the stage, so it's a stucked one)
THANKS A LOT!!!

Comment: Ooh, it's getting kinda complex now. You could have another method on the child that is called on the Button press that moves the player, then returns a bool determining if it would be able to make the move and then if that bool returned true, allow the player to move and send the directions out. Just thinking without writing it out , it sounds like this may not be the best method, but you never know until you implement it.